# Animating child view outside of parent

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am trying to animate a view outside of its parent view and when I do the child view is not able to animate beyond its parent. I solved this by using the `setClipChildren(false)` and it worked... When the view is animated *up*. When I animate the view *down* the image is still hidden.

Here is the code that works. This code will animate a tile button to the top of the screen:

```
private void setGameBoard(){

        brickWall.setClipChildren(false);
        brickWall.setClipToPadding(false);

        //Build game board
        for(int ii = 0; ii < brickRows;ii++){
            final int x = ii;

            //Build table rows
            row = new TableRow(this.getApplicationContext());
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50));
            row.setClipChildren(false);
            row.setClipToPadding(false);

           // row.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.colorAccent, null));

            //Build table tiles
            for(int jj=0; jj < brickColumns; jj++){
                final int y = jj;
                final Brick tile = new Brick(this);
                tile.setClipBounds(null);

                tile.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.colorPrimary, null));

                //Set margins to create look of tic-tac-toe
                TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                           150, 75);
                lp.setMargins(0,0,0,0);


                //lp.weight = 1;
                tile.setLayoutParams(lp);

                tile.setWidth(3);
                tile.setHeight(10);
                tile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(tile.getHits() == 0){
                            tile.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),
                                    R.color.colorGreen, null));
                            tile.addHit();
                        } else if (tile.getHits() == 1){
                            tile.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),
                                    R.color.colorYellow, null));
                            tile.addHit();
                        }else if(tile.getHits() == 2){
                            brokenBricks++;

                            float bottomOfScreen = getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
                                    .heightPixels;

                            ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tile, "translationY",
                                    -2000);
// 2
                            objectAnimator.setDuration(2000);
                            tile.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
                            objectAnimator.start();
                            //tile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            if(isRevealComplete()){
                                brickWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                row.addView(tile);
            }

            brickWall.addView(row);
        }
    }
```

But when I adjust where the view to go to the bottom of the screen, the view below it is "swallowed" and is hidden when it gets to the bottom of the parent view:

```
 private void setGameBoard(){

        brickWall.setClipChildren(false);
        brickWall.setClipToPadding(false);

        //Build game board
        for(int ii = 0; ii < brickRows;ii++){
            final int x = ii;

            //Build table rows
            row = new TableRow(this.getApplicationContext());
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50));
            row.setClipChildren(false);
            row.setClipToPadding(false);

           // row.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.colorAccent, null));

            //Build table tiles
            for(int jj=0; jj < brickColumns; jj++){
                final int y = jj;
                final Brick tile = new Brick(this);
                tile.setClipBounds(null);

                tile.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.colorPrimary, null));

                //Set margins to create look of tic-tac-toe
                TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                           150, 75);
                lp.setMargins(0,0,0,0);


                //lp.weight = 1;
                tile.setLayoutParams(lp);

                tile.setWidth(3);
                tile.setHeight(10);
                tile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(tile.getHits() == 0){
                            tile.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),
                                    R.color.colorGreen, null));
                            tile.addHit();
                        } else if (tile.getHits() == 1){
                            tile.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),
                                    R.color.colorYellow, null));
                            tile.addHit();
                        }else if(tile.getHits() == 2){
                            brokenBricks++;

                            float bottomOfScreen = getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
                                    .heightPixels;

                            ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tile, "translationY",
                                    2000);
                            objectAnimator.setDuration(2000);
                            tile.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
                            objectAnimator.start();
                            //tile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            if(isRevealComplete()){
                                brickWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                row.addView(tile);
            }

            brickWall.addView(row);
        }
    }
```

So my question is: ***How can I animate a child view outside of a parent view below the child view?***

**UPDATE 1**

If I remove the tiles below the tile I am trying to drop, then I am able to see the desired effect until there is another tile below it, at which point the dropping tile will go "behind" the tile that is still there. So how do I get the dropping tile to move over the children below it?

**UPDATE 2**

One new things I've noticed is that if I move the button left or up, it works fine; but, if move it down or to the right it goes behind the other views. This leads me to believe that buttons created after the current tile have a different effect.

Comment: as an ultra-dirty trick just to test, can you add some elevation (1dp) to the animated view? elevation changes the z-order of the Views so I suspect this could have an impact in your problem. It can be a workaround, but the root problem needs more investigation !

Comment: I've tried doing that and it didn't have any impact.

Comment: besides, have you considered using a lightweight FrameLayout and just placing the tiles with the correct spacing? That would eliminate nested layouts and make the overall resulting structure lighter. I'd take this way, but I don't know the specifics of your app, in my experience setClipChildren() works best the flatter the layout is.

Comment: also, can you set setClipChildren(false) to the Layout containing brickWall ? if its height is wrap_content this might explain your bottom clipping

Comment: I've set the `setClipChildren` to both the row and the container (everywhere). One new things I've noticed is that if I move the button left or up, it works fine; but, if move it down or to the right it goes behind the other views. This leads me to believe that buttons created after the current tile have a different effect.

Comment: i think what's going on is, tiles created after that button have a higher z-order. I have implemented in the past something that works really well for these situations, that is creating a Bitmap out of the view with its contents, hiding the view, then animating this "ghost image" in dispatchDraw(), where you have absolute power to draw over everything., or add it as another View, over the rest of stuff. Can detail more if you're interested.

Comment: @rupps I'd love to see what you have. Please feel free to share!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so in the alternate approach I suggest, I'd use a helper class `FlyOverView` that takes a "photo" of any view then animates it to whichever desired coordinates. Once the animation is running, you then can hide / delete the original view, as what is moving around the screen is just an image blitted over the canvas. You won't have to worry about clipping other views, etc.

You'll need to declare this `FlyOverView` on an outer container of your brick system, and that layout has to cover the whole area where you intend the animation to be visible. So I'd suggest to use the following as you root container, it's just a `FrameLayout` where you'll draw stuff over its children.

```
package whatever;

public class GameRootLayout extends FrameLayout {

    // the currently-animating effect, if any
    private FlyOverView mFlyOverView;

    public GameRootLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context,attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        // draw the children            
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        // draw our stuff
        if (mFlyOverView != null) {
            mFlyOverView.delegate_draw(canvas);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Starts a flyover animation for the specified view. 
     * It will "fly" to the desired position with an alpha / translation / rotation effect
     *
     * @param viewToFly The view to fly
     * @param targetX The target X coordinate
     * @param targetY The target Y coordinate
     */

    public void addFlyOver(View viewToFly, @Px int targetX, @Px int targetY) {
        if (mFlyOverView != null) mFlyOverView.cancel();
        mFlyOverView = new FlyOverView(this, viewToFly, targetX, targetY, new FlyOverView.OnFlyOverFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFlyOverFinishedListener() {
                mFlyOverView = null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

that you can use as the container

```
  <whatever.GameRootLayout
          android:id="@+id/gameRootLayout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

          .
          .
    </whatever.GameRootLayout>
```

Then the FlyOverView itself:

```
package com.regaliz.gui.fx;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.annotation.Px;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;


/**
 * Neat animation that captures a layer bitmap and "flies" it to the corner of the screen, used to create
 * an "added to playlist" effect or something like that. The method delegate_draw() must be called from the
 * parent view to update the animation
 *
 * @author rupps'2014
 * license public domain, attribution appreciated
 */

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class FlyOverView {

    public  static final int DEFAULT_DURATION = 1000;
    private static final String TAG = "FlyOverView";
    private static final boolean LOG_ON = false;

    private ObjectAnimator mFlyoverAnimation;

    private float mCurrentX, mCurrentY;
    private Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    private View mParentView = null;
    private OnFlyOverFinishedListener mOnFlyOverFinishedListener;

    public interface OnFlyOverFinishedListener {
        void onFlyOverFinishedListener();
    }

    /**
     * Creates the FlyOver effect
     *
     * @param parent    Container View to invalidate. That view has to call this class' delegate_draw() in its dispatchDraw().
     * @param viewToFly Target View to animate
     * @param finalX    Final X coordinate
     * @param finalY    Final Y coordinate
     */

    public FlyOverView(View parent, View viewToFly, @Px int finalX, @Px int finalY, OnFlyOverFinishedListener listener) {
        setupFlyOver(parent, viewToFly, finalX, finalY, DEFAULT_DURATION, listener);
    }

    /**
     * Creates the FlyOver effect
     *
     * @param parent    Container View to invalidate. That view has to call this class' delegate_draw() in its dispatchDraw().
     * @param viewToFly Target View to animate
     * @param finalX    Final X coordinate
     * @param finalY    Final Y coordinate
     * @param duration  Animation duration
     */

    public FlyOverView(View parent, View viewToFly, @Px int finalX, @Px int finalY, int duration, OnFlyOverFinishedListener listener) {
        setupFlyOver(parent, viewToFly, finalX, finalY, duration, listener);
    }

    /**
     * cancels current animation from the outside
     */
    public void cancel() {
        if (mFlyoverAnimation != null) mFlyoverAnimation.cancel();
    }

    private void setupFlyOver(View parentContainer, View viewToFly, @Px int finalX, @Px int finalY, int duration, OnFlyOverFinishedListener listener) {


        int[] location = new int[2];

        mParentView = parentContainer;
        mOnFlyOverFinishedListener = listener;
        viewToFly.getLocationInWindow(location);

        int 
            sourceX = location[0],
            sourceY = location[1];

        if (LOG_ON) Log.v(TAG, "FlyOverView, item " + viewToFly+", finals "+finalX+", "+finalY+", sources "+sourceX+", "+sourceY+ " duration "+duration);

         /* Animation definition table */

        mFlyoverAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(
            this,
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("translationX", sourceX, finalX),
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("translationY", sourceY, finalY),
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleAlpha", 1, 0.2f) // not to 0 so we see the end of the effect in other properties
        );

        mFlyoverAnimation.setDuration(duration);
        mFlyoverAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
        mFlyoverAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        mFlyoverAnimation.addListener(new SimpleAnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                if (LOG_ON) Log.v(TAG, "FlyOver: End");
                mParentView.invalidate();
                if (mBitmap != null) mBitmap.recycle(); // just for safety
                mBitmap = null;
                mOnFlyOverFinishedListener.onFlyOverFinishedListener();
            }
        });

        // take snapshot of viewToFly
        viewToFly.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewToFly.getDrawingCache());
        viewToFly.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        mFlyoverAnimation.start();

    }

    // ANIMATOR setter
    public void setTranslationX(float position) {
        mCurrentX = position;
    }

    // ANIMATOR setter
    public void setTranslationY(float position) {
        mCurrentY = position;
    }

    // ANIMATOR setter
    // as this will be called in every iteration, we set here all parameters at once then call invalidate,
    // rather than separately
    public void setScaleAlpha(float position) {

        mPaint.setAlpha((int) (100 * position));
        mMatrix.setScale(position, position);
        mMatrix.postRotate(360 * position); // asemos de to'
        mMatrix.postTranslate(mCurrentX, mCurrentY);

        mParentView.invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * This has to be called from the root container's dispatchDraw()
     * in order to update the animation.
     */

    public void delegate_draw(Canvas c) {
        if (LOG_ON) Log.v(TAG, "CX " + mCurrentX + ", CY " + mCurrentY);
        c.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mMatrix, mPaint);
    }

    private abstract class SimpleAnimationListener implements Animator.AnimatorListener {
        @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to animate any view, you just have to call the function in the game root layout:

```
GameRootLayout rootLayout = (GameRootLayout)findViewById(...);
.
.
rootLayout.addFlyOver(yourBrick, targetX, targetY);
```

This example also applies alpha and rotation to the view, but you can tune it easily to your needs.

I hope this can inspire you, if you have any question feel free to ask !

Comment: So this works really well. Need to adjust the animations a bit, I don't like how it shrinks as it gets to the bottom of the page, but other than that, it works really well.

Comment: Glad you like it, yeah, it's a bit exaggerated, I use it on a media player where the thumbnails are big, so the effect is meant as they get "swallowed" by a top corner. To change it to your needs just change in **setScaleAlpha** , position ranges from 1.0 to 0.0 decreasing

Answer (score 11):

Although the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44186775/1083957) provided by [rupps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108397/rupps) may solve the problem, but personally I would **not** use that approach, because:

- It allocates `Bitmap` object on the main thread: you should strive not to do that unless in a real need.
- It *unnecessarily* * adds  boilerplate to the codebase.

<sup>* Unnecessarily, because framework provides appropriate API, which is mentioned below.</sup>

So, the problem you are trying to solve is to animate a `View` out of the bounds of it's parent. Let's get acquainted with [`ViewOverlay`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOverlay.html) API:

> An overlay is an extra layer that sits on top of a View (the "host view") which is drawn after all other content in that view (including children, if the view is a ViewGroup). Interaction with the overlay layer is done by adding and removing drawables.

As mentioned by [Israel Ferrer Camacho](https://twitter.com/rallat) in his ["Smoke & Mirrors" talk](https://youtu.be/912hbLVdIQE?t=449):

> `ViewOverlay` is gonna be your best friend forever ... in animations.

As an example use cases you can see [this](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/09/19/crossing-boundaries-with-the-new-android-viewoverlay/):

[image]
<sup>Animating icons using `ViewOverlay` API. This looks like [shared element transition](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions)?? Well, that's because [Transitions API](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/overview.html) internally uses `ViewOverlay`.</sup>

Also [a nice example](http://lafosca.cat/viewoverlay-in-android/) by [Dave Smith](https://twitter.com/devunwired), demonstrating difference between using `ViewOverlay` and `Animator`:

[image]

In order to complete the answer, I'll post a chunk of code from Dave Smith's example. The usage is as simple as this:

```
container.getOverlay().add(button);
```

The `button` would be *"overlayed"* atop of container right in the coordinates where it is in the view hierarchy. Now you can perform animations on this `button`, but the crucial point is to remove the overlay once you do not need it:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {
    container.getOverlay().remove(button);
}
```

Comment: yeah well this OverlayView was added after I did that code, by the way, it does pretty much the same (if you take a look at the source code), only if I may say, my solution is way straighter to the point as the API  takes into account many edge cases that don't apply in the OP case. Regarding Bitmaps on main thread, i'm just taking one small View Bitmap cache, not loading or blocking anything, and the bitmap is not decoded but natively blitted. The overhead to create a thread in this situation would be worse.

Comment: I am not inclined to claim, that your implementation is *worse* than the implementation I provided. It's just another angle and another implementation which may or may not be better in some aspects. Nevertheless, if I were to implement such a feature I would totally go with APIs that platform provides (that handles all the edge cases as you mentioned), rather reinventing a wheel on my own.

Comment: Concerning *"pretty much the same"*, I'm not sure that's true, because [`ViewOverlay` uses `DisplayList`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewOverlay.java#143), not a `Bitmap`, which is far more efficient.

Comment: And, by the way, as the OP just wants, in the context of his game, perform some effects over fallling bricks (the overlay view will have the same contents), my solution skips the overhead of creating and initializing the drawable, ArrayList allocation, and rest of stuff in ViewOverlay designed for complex effects that are not needed, which if we get picky, is certainly something to bear in mind, specially in the context of a game.

Comment: Is this array list what is causing the last element to be removed from the view, rather the image that was selected?

Comment: Concerning usage of `DisplayList`: the [original commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/36d9a6dfba1a3c39aa3224fdef15cb79e2e9b9a0%5E%21/#F0), where that message is introduced, has been made on Jan 2017 and it seems like it hasn't yet been released (because I cannot find that in my local machine's sources). Nevertheless, I cannot argue concerning that, as long as Chris Craik has certainly better understandings of that than I do. Concerning drawables: sorry, but storing a drawable and **creating** a `Bitmap` cannot be considered as *"exactly the same"*.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai, cannot get what you mean. Could you clarify or rephrase your question?

Comment: Yes, so I implemented the code using your example, and while the animation is correct and works as expected, the last brick in my row disappears, rather than the brick that was selected. So I have 6 bricks in a row, and if I tap on brick 3, then brick 3 animates as expected, but brick 6 is removed from the view.

Comment: Hi @BlackSamurai, the example only animates on top of your brick, the disappearing logic is part of your code

Comment: Not so sure about that @rupps considering when I remove the animation code, the correct brick is removed. More specifically, when I remove the overlay code.

Comment: can u post the failing code? it's impossible the overlay effect can affect your views :)

Comment: I'll create a new question @rupps

Comment: Here is the new question @rupps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209407/viewoverlay-code-is-remving-last-view-in-row

Comment: How to use that object again like Whatsapp voice delete animation?