# ViewOverlay Code is Removing Last View in Row

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to animate a brick falling, and to create the brick I add rows to a `TableLayout` and then add buttons to each row. The issue I am having is that when I animate the brick falling, the last button in the row is removed, rather than the brick that was animated. Here is my code:

```
 private void setGameBoard(){

        brickWall.setClipChildren(false);
        brickWall.setClipToPadding(false);

        //Build game board
        for(int ii = 0; ii < brickRows;ii++){
            final int x = ii;

            //Build table rows
            row = new TableRow(this.getApplicationContext());
            row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            row.setClipChildren(false);
            row.setClipToPadding(false);

            // row.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.colorAccent, null));

            //Build table tiles
            for(int jj=0; jj < brickColumns; jj++){
                final int y = jj;
                final Brick tile = new Brick(this);


                tile.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.colorPrimary, null));

                //Set margins to create look of tic-tac-toe
                TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
                lp.setMargins(0,0,0,0);


                //lp.weight = 1;
                tile.setLayoutParams(lp);

                if(ii % 2 == 0){
                    tile.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.brick02, null));
                }else if(ii % 3 == 0){
                    tile.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.brick03, null));
                }else if(ii % 4 == 0){
                    tile.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.brick04, null));
                }else{
                    tile.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.brick01, null));
                }



                tile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(tile.getHits() == 0){
                            tile.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.brick01_broken01));
                            tile.addHit();
                        } else if (tile.getHits() == 1){
                            tile.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.brick01_broken02));
                            tile.addHit();
                        }else if(tile.getHits() == 2){
                            brokenBricks++;

                            float bottomOfScreen = getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
                                    .heightPixels;

                            final ViewGroup vg  = (ViewGroup) brickWall.getParent().getParent();
                            vg.getOverlay().add(tile);

                            ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tile, "translationY", brickWall.getHeight());
                            ObjectAnimator rotate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tile, "rotation", 0, 360);

                            rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                            rotate.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
                            rotate.setDuration(350);

                            anim.setDuration(2000);
                            tile.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
                            anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animator arg0) {
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator arg0) {
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {
                                    vg.getOverlay().remove(tile);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator arg0) {
                                    vg.getOverlay().remove(tile);
                                }
                            });

                            anim.setDuration(2000);

                            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
                            set.playTogether(anim, rotate);
                            set.start();

                            //tile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            if(isRevealComplete()){
                                brickWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                row.addView(tile);

            }

            brickWall.addView(row);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: oh! it's using the API ViewOverlay! hmmm, I haven't used that API so I have no idea what can be going on ! Which line do you think it's causing the brick to disappear?

Comment: @rupps it was the simplest solution, although not sure how much of solution it is at this point when it's not working as expected.  :)

Comment: to be honest, I don't really know how the overlay works, you're adding a Brick (which is a View right?) to the Overlay? isn't it supposed to be a Drawable?

Comment: BTW I'd suggest to also take a look at my solution, I think is more adequate for your problem

Comment: @rupps I may end up doing that. The only issue is that it is quite a bit more code that what is being used here. But if i can't get this to work, then I will have no choice.

Comment: i guess it might have something to do with the fact you're adding the view as overlay, I don't know if it internally takes a snapshot of the view. Can't you just put a breakpoint at **vg.getOverlay().remove(tile);** and checkout what "tile" and "vg.getOverlay()" is at that point?

Comment: @rupps it looks like what is happening is that when the view is removed, the other tiles shift over and take it's place. I've played with it a bit and if I remove an entire row, all the bricks shift up one row.

Comment: @BlackSamurai Ohhh! that's because you're using LinearLayouts (that's what tablelayouts are). You have 3 options by order of complexity: (1) don't remove the tile, just change its visibility to INVISIBLE (that way the Layout will take it into consideration as opposed to GONE), (2) change the root to a flat FrameLayout and position the tiles horizontally and vertically, or (3) Create a "WallBrickView" that draws the tiles using drawRect(). That's quite a bit of work, but it would be the most efficient.

Comment: Why does it maintain it's spacing when the view group isn't used then @rupps?

Comment: i think i might need a screenshot  ... i more or less guess what you're into, but can only speculate

Comment: it looks like this is expected behavior for this workaround