# Shared element animation between RecyclerView item and CollapsingToolbar within same activity

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, android-view

In my application I have a list of items displayed through a `RecyclerView` adapter. If I click on an item a new `Fragment` in started within the same `Activity`. The layout of my item and my Activity look (simplified) like this:

**Activity layout:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:transitionName="image" ... />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar ... />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout ... />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout... />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Item Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/itemImage"
        android:transitionName="image" />

    <LinearLayout>

        <TextView ... />

        <TextView ... />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, if the new fragment is started by an item click, I would like to add an animation of the item image to the `ImageView` in the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. I read [the article](http://guides.codepath.com/android/shared-element-activity-transition) about ShareElement animations but this does not work here because this is not a real ShareElement animation. The target `ImageView` is not in the new fragment neither I have to start a new activity (I only make the target `ImageView` visible in the new `Fragment`). So how would I create such an animation in this case?

Comment: Is the RecyclerView  in the same layout that CollapsingToolbarLayout ?

Comment: No it is in another Fragment and the CollapsingToolbarLayout in the layout of the activity.

Comment: The another Fragment is handle by the same Activity that the CollapsingToolbar or another ?

Comment: Yes everything is within the same Activity! Do you have another idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes i have another idea , i will try to adpat it to your issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, you are trying to animate a view from one layout to another.

I think this can be achieved using *ViewOverlays API*. You can see a detailed answer about that API [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44195527/1083957).

Now in your case, what you'll end up with is you'd add your `ImageView` to the `ViewGroupOverlay` of the root layout:

```
    final ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content);
    container.getOverlay().add(imageView);
    ...
```

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroupOverlay.html#add(android.view.View)):

> If the view has a parent, the view will be removed from that parent before being added to the overlay.

Thus, as soon as you perform `getOverlay().add(imageView)` the view would be removed from it's parent. Now you are free to create your animation and move the `imageView` to the final destination.

```
    final ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content);
    container.getOverlay().add(imageView);

    // animate imageView by any API, e.g. ViewPropertyHolder
    imageView.animate()
             .x(finalX)
             .y(finalY)
             .setDuration(duration)
             .setInterpolator(interpolator)
             .withEndAction(() -> {
                // crucial point, remove the overlay
                container.getOverlay().remove(imageView);

                // add this `imageView` to the destination layout
                destLayout.addView(imageView);
             })
```

[Here's](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/09/19/crossing-boundaries-with-the-new-android-viewoverlay/) a similar feature you're trying to implement:

[image]